# I am making a gravity simulator in javascript, and I have no idea how to make a collision work

Tags: javascript, collision, gravity

I want it to work with these algorithms: 1:The smaller mass collides with the larger mass. 2: The smaller mass' mass and velocity are added to the larger mass. Can you help me? Link to the project: https://jsfiddle.net/awesomespaceman/bq60znj9/54/

I use JsFiddle to code my projects. I have tried putting a collision dynamics function and it isnt working at all. Also, putting 0 instead of NaN won't work. This is the function:

```
function collisionDynamics(radius, mass1, mass2) {
  if (mass1.x + radius >= mass2.x - radius && mass1.x <= mass2.x + radius) {
    if (mass1.y + radius >= mass2.y - radius && mass1.y <= mass2.y + radius) {
      if (mass1 > mass2) {

        mass1 += mass2;
        mass2 = NaN;
      } else {
        mass2 += mass1;
        mass1 = NaN
      }
    }
  }
}
collisionDynamics(4, massI, massesLen);
```

Expected result: The smaller mass collides with the larger mass, and the larger mass absorbs its mass and velocity.

Actual result: The two masses phase through each other without any interaction besides gravitational interaction.They are both ricocheted across the simulation without a collision.

Comment: well you need to adjust the velocities as well

Comment: I understand. I am just adding the mass first before I can transfer velocities.

Comment: so youre making some kind of fluid simulation where oen mass gets absorbed ?

Comment: or do you just want to bounce it off ?

Comment: I want the two masses to become one mass.

Comment: well IF you want to make it haldway realistic I would go with implementing  impulse for the two objects (probably wanna use vectors for velocity): basically speed after collision of the bigger mass gets calculated v+=(v1*m1)-(v2*m2) (I tihnk that was correct impulse formula need to look it up)

Comment: did you define classes for mass ? if so please add an example of your implementation for addition

Comment: Sounds good for the velocity, but can you look at my project and see what is wrong with the collision dynamics? Also, I think they are all in one class, called innerSolarSystem.

Comment: oh completely missed the link (nvm my comment)

Comment: lol maybe you shoulve tried figuring out collision on an easier example ^^

Comment: Okay. Maybe I should look at another project for info.

Comment: oO I think the acceleration is already wrong

Comment: It doesnt even seem to get to the collision part

Comment: oh nevermind I just always single clicked without drawing a velocity vector (be aware of that case ^^)

Comment: for collision i propose a structure like this : Math.abs(mass1.x -mass2.x) < radius*2 (or mass1.radius+mas2.raious)

Comment: btw why are you passing the length of the masses as mass2 ?

Comment: I would also propose being really careful comparing the radius (range 4) to the position of the planet (-0.000001-0.0000001 (+-))

Comment: Oh. I should change that.

Answer (score -2):

I think I got it to work

I used Math.abs to calculate the difference between the two points and check if its smaller than the radius (divided by some scaling) (line 351/352)

then similar to what you did check for which mass is greater (line 353) and add them together (line 355 /358)

aside from that I fixed passing the length instead of the mass (line 435 ff )and comparing with every element in the loop

I also introduced a new variable to set if its destroyed just to make sure it doesnt render anymore and added a small method to slow down the animations

```js
  const names = [ "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Ceres", "Nemesis","Dephanov","Podaohiri","Xeviea","Noluna","Hoibos","Yenope","Straditov","Zoenov","Sapus","Kepler","Pasteur","Boltzmann","Gezeacarro","Xagricury","Vulmone","Ochion","Liavis","Roitis","Galoria","Phucohiri","Your Anus"]
  
var addedmasses = document.getElementById("addedMasses")
  class nBodyProblem {
    constructor(params) {
      this.g = params.g;
      this.dt = params.dt;
      this.softeningConstant = params.softeningConstant;
  
      this.masses = params.masses;
    }
  
    updatePositionVectors() {
      const massesLen = this.masses.length;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < massesLen; i++) {
        const massI = this.masses[i];
  
        massI.x += massI.vx * this.dt;
        massI.y += massI.vy * this.dt;
        massI.z += massI.vz * this.dt;
      }
  
      return this;
    }
  
    updateVelocityVectors() {
      const massesLen = this.masses.length;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < massesLen; i++) {
        const massI = this.masses[i];
  
        massI.vx += massI.ax * this.dt;
        massI.vy += massI.ay * this.dt;
        massI.vz += massI.az * this.dt;
      }
    }
  
    updateAccelerationVectors() {
      const massesLen = this.masses.length;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < massesLen; i++) {
        let ax = 0;
        let ay = 0;
        let az = 0;
  
        const massI = this.masses[i];
  
        for (let j = 0; j < massesLen; j++) {
          if (i !== j) {
            const massJ = this.masses[j];
  
            const dx = massJ.x - massI.x;
            const dy = massJ.y - massI.y;
            const dz = massJ.z - massI.z;
  
            const distSq = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
  
            const f =
              (this.g * massJ.m) /
              (distSq * Math.sqrt(distSq + this.softeningConstant));
  
            ax += dx * f;
            ay += dy * f;
            az += dz * f;
          }
        }
  
        massI.ax = ax;
        massI.ay = ay;
        massI.az = az;
      }
  
      return this;
    }
  }
  
  /*
   * Inputs for our nBodyProblem
   */
  
  const g = 39.5;
  const dt = 0.008; //0.005 years is equal to 1.825 days
  const softeningConstant = 0.15;
  
  const masses = [{
      name: "Sun", //We use solar masses as the unit of mass, so the mass of the Sun is exactly 1
      m: 1,
      x: -1.50324727873647e-6,
      y: -3.93762725944737e-6,
      z: -4.86567877183925e-8,
      vx: 3.1669325898331e-5,
      vy: -6.85489559263319e-6,
      vz: -7.90076642683254e-7,
      radius:5
    },
    {
      name: "Mercury",
      m: 1.65956463e-7,
      x: -0.346390408691506,
      y: -0.272465544507684,
      z: 0.00951633403684172,
      vx: 4.25144321778261,
      vy: -7.61778341043381,
      vz: -1.01249478093275,
      radius:0.5
    },
    {
      name: "Venus",
      m: 2.44699613e-6,
      x: -0.168003526072526,
      y: 0.698844725464528,
      z: 0.0192761582256879,
      vx: -7.2077847105093,
      vy: -1.76778886124455,
      vz: 0.391700036358566,
      radius:1
    },
    {
      name: "Earth",
      m: 3.0024584e-6,
      x: 0.648778995445634,
      y: 0.747796691108466,
      z: -3.22953591923124e-5,
      vx: -4.85085525059392,
      vy: 4.09601538682312,
      vz: -0.000258553333317722,
      radius:1
    },
    {
      m: 3.213e-7,
      name: "Mars",
      x: -0.574871406752105,
      y: -1.395455041953879,
      z: -0.01515164037265145,
      vx: 4.9225288800471425,
      vy: -1.5065904473191791,
      vz: -0.1524041758922603,
      radius:0.5
    }
  ];
  
  /*
   * Create an instance of the nBodyProblem with the inputs above
   * We clone the masses array by parsing a stringified version of it so that we can reset the simulator with a minimum amount of fuss
   */ 
  
  const innerSolarSystem = new nBodyProblem({
    g,
    dt,
    masses: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(masses)),   
    softeningConstant
  });
  
  /*
   * Motion trails
   */
  
  class Manifestation {
    constructor(ctx, trailLength, radius) {
      this.ctx = ctx;
    
      this.trailLength = trailLength;
  
      this.radius = radius;
  
      this.positions = [];
    }
  
    storePosition(x, y) {
      this.positions.push({
        x,
        y
      });
  
      if (this.positions.length > this.trailLength) this.positions.shift();
    }
  
    draw(x, y) {
      this.storePosition(x, y);
  
      const positionsLen = this.positions.length;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < positionsLen; i++) {
        let transparency;
        let circleScaleFactor;
  
        const scaleFactor = i / positionsLen;
  
        if (i === positionsLen - 1) {
          transparency = 1;
          circleScaleFactor = 1;
        } else {
          transparency = scaleFactor / 2;      
          circleScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        }
  
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(
          this.positions[i].x,
          this.positions[i].y,
          circleScaleFactor * this.radius,
          0,
          2 * Math.PI
        );
        this.ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(0, 153, 193, ${transparency})`;
  
        this.ctx.fill();
      }
    }
  }
  
  /*
   * Get the canvas element and its context from the DOM
   */
  
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  /*
   * Full screen action
   */
  
  const width = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
  const height = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
  
  /*
   * Animation constants
   *
   * scale is the number of pixels per astronomical units
   *
   * radius is the radius of the circle that represents the current position of a mass
   *
   * trailLength is the number of previous positions that we should draw in the motion trail
   */
  
  const scale = 70;
const radius = 4;
  const trailLength = 35;
  
  /*
   * Iterate over the masses being simulated and add a visual manifestation for each of them
   */
  
  const populateManifestations = masses => {
    masses.forEach(
      mass =>
      (mass["manifestation"] = new Manifestation(
        ctx,
        trailLength,
        radius
      ))
    );
  };
  
  populateManifestations(innerSolarSystem.masses);

  /*
   * Click the reset button to reset the simulation
  */

  document.querySelector('#reset-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    innerSolarSystem.masses = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(masses));
    populateManifestations(innerSolarSystem.masses);       
  }, false);
  
  /*
   * Code for adding masses with you mouse
   */
  
  //Step 1.
  
  let mousePressX = 0;
  let mousePressY = 0;
  
  //Step 2.
  
  let currentMouseX = 0;
  let currentMouseY = 0;
  
  //Step 3.
  
  let dragging = false;
      
  //Step 4.
  
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousedown",
    e => {
      mousePressX = e.clientX;
      mousePressY = e.clientY;
      dragging = true;
    },
    false
  );
  
  //Step 5
  
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    e => {
      currentMouseX = e.clientX;
      currentMouseY = e.clientY;
    },
    false
  );
  
  //Step 6
 
  const massesList = addedmasses;
     
  
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mouseup",
    e => {
      const x = (mousePressX - width / 2) / scale;
      const y = (mousePressY - height / 2) / scale;
      const z = 0;
      const vx = (e.clientX - mousePressX) / 35;
      const vy = (e.clientY - mousePressY) / 35;
      const vz = 0;
  
      innerSolarSystem.masses.push({
    name: names[Math.floor(Math.random()*21)],
        m: parseFloat(massesList.value),
        x,
        y,
        z,
        vx,
        vy,
        vz,
        manifestation: new Manifestation(ctx, trailLength, radius),
        
        
      });
  
      dragging = false;
    },
    false
  );
  
  /*
   * The animate function that sets everything in motion.
   * We run it 60 times a second with the help of requestAnimationFrame
   */
  function collisionDynamics(radius, mass1, mass2){
  if(mass1.destroyed||mass2.destroyed){
   return;
  }
  
  if( Math.abs(mass1.x -mass2.x) < radius/60){
  if( Math.abs(mass1.y -mass2.y) < radius/60){
    if(mass1.m>mass2.m){

    mass1.m+= mass2.m;
    mass2.destroyed = true;
    }else{
    mass2.m+=mass1.m;
    
    mass1.destroyed = true;    }
  }
  }
  }
  let framect=0;
  const animate = () => {
   framect++;
    if(framect%5==0){
     animateR();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  
  const animateR = () => {
    /*
     * Advance our simulation by one step
     */
  
    innerSolarSystem
      .updatePositionVectors()
      .updateAccelerationVectors()
      .updateVelocityVectors();
     
    /*
     * Clear the canvas in preparation for the next drawing cycle
     */
  
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
    const massesLen = innerSolarSystem.masses.length;
  
    /*
     * Let us draw some masses!
     */
  
    for (let i = 0; i < massesLen; i++) {
      const massI = innerSolarSystem.masses[i];
  
  if(massI.destroyed){
  continue;
  }
      /*
       * The origin (x = 0, y = 0) of the canvas coordinate system is in the top left corner
       * To prevent our simulation from being centered on the top left corner, include the x and y offsets
       * So that it is centered smack in the middle of the canvas
       */
  
      const x = width / 2 + massI.x * scale;
      const y = height / 2 + massI.y * scale;

      /*
       * Draw our motion trail
       */
  
      massI.manifestation.draw(x, y);
  
      /*
       * If the mass has a name, draw it onto the canvas next to the leading circle of the motion trail
       */
  
      if (massI.name) {
        ctx.font = "15px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(massI.name, x + 12, y + 4);
        ctx.fill();
      }
      
      /*
       * Stop masses from escaping the bounds of the viewport
       * If either condition is met, the velocity of the mass will be reversed
       * And the mass will bounce back into the inner solar system
       */

      if (x < radius || x > width - radius) massI.vx = -massI.vx;
  
      if (y < radius || y > height - radius) massI.vy = -massI.vy;
      for(let j=0;j<massesLen;j++){
      if(j!=i){
       collisionDynamics(4, massI, innerSolarSystem.masses[j]);
      }
      
      }
     
    }
  
    /*
     * Draw the line which indicates direction and velocity of a mass that is about to be added when the mouse is being dragged
     */
  
    if (dragging) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(mousePressX, mousePressY);
      ctx.lineTo(currentMouseX, currentMouseY);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    
  };

  animate();
```

```html
<section id="controls-wrapper">
  <label>Mass of Added Planet(in solar masses)</label>
  <li><input type="text" name="field" class="textbox" id = "addedMasses"/>
  </li>
  <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
</section>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: That mountain of code doesn't really explain what the problem was, nor what the solution is.

Comment: You might want to attribute your answer to the source you plagiarized it from: https://css-tricks.com/creating-your-own-gravity-and-space-simulator/

Comment: I only plagiarized from the link in the question

Comment: oh yeah its quite similar :o